# Unity3d change Texture2D color

Tags: c#, android, mobile, unity-game-engine

In Unity3d, how to change `Texture2D` color to black and white.....I am using unity 5, bew UI Canvas, for `ImageUI` Texture want to change color black and white..

I tried with `texture.SetPixels();` and `getPixelsbilliner();` as per [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixelBilinear.html).

Thanks,
Adi.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick.

```
void Start() {
    GetComponent.<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = Texture2D.blackTexture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
myImageCompenent.material.color = wantedColor;
```

this sets an image color, just as you see in the editor.